# illegal start of expression error in virtual keyboard code in java

Tags: java, virtual, keypad

I am getting an error `illegal start of expression` in the code below, at line -> `public class hindilang` , I have seen other questions and answers on this site, but i don't know where i am going wrong ??

```
    abstract class lang extends JFrame implements KeyListener
    {
    boolean flag=false;
    String firstRow[] = {">","=","*","_","<","{","(","'","?","-","!","[",")"};
    String secondRow[] = {"|","#",".",":","&","@","]","/","}",",","$","^","~"};
    String thirdRow[] = {"d","v","m","y","e","k","a","j","z","3","0","9"};
    String fourthRow[] = {"r","b","p","o","h","w","g","x","1","7","5","4"};
    String fifthRow[] = {"f","c","n","s","l","t","q","u","i","6","2","8"};
    String sixthRow[] = {"Space","Back","Capslock","Clear","Show me mappings"};
    JButton first[] = new JButton[13];
    JButton second[] = new JButton[13];
    JButton third[] = new JButton[12];
    JButton fourth[] = new JButton[12];
    JButton fifth[]=new JButton[12];
    JButton sixth[]=new JButton[5];
    int count=0;
    Panel main = new Panel();
    Panel keys1 = new Panel();
    Panel keys2 = new Panel();
    Panel keys3 = new Panel();
    Panel keys4 = new Panel();
    Panel keys5 = new Panel();
    Panel keys6 = new Panel();
    Panel text = new Panel();
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    String strText = "";
    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;
    private JTextField textField;

    public lang()
    {
    super("Typing Application");
    label1 = new JLabel("Type some text using your keyboard. The keys you press will be
    "+ "highlighed and the text will be displayed");
    add(label1);
    label2 = new JLabel("Note: clicking the buttons with your mouse will not perform
    any action");
    add(label2);
    textField = new JTextField(30);
    textField.setEditable(false);
    TextFieldHandler handler = new TextFieldHandler();
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(6,6));
    main.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));
    keys1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,13));
    keys2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,13));
    keys3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,14));
    keys4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,12));
    keys5.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,11));
    keys6.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
    text.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1,1));
    text.add(textArea);

    for(int i=0; i<13; i++)
    {
    first[i] = new JButton(firstRow[i]);
    first[i].setSize(100,100);
    keys1.add(first[i]);
    first[i].addActionListener(new TextAreaHandler());
    }



    main.add(keys1);
    for(int i=0; i<13; i++)
    {
    second[i] = new JButton(secondRow[i]);
    second[i].setBackground(Color.white);
    keys2.add(second[i]);
    second[i].addActionListener(new TextAreaHandler());
    }

    main.add(keys2);

    for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
    String t=i+"";
    String m="icon";
    String n=".gif";
    String s=m+t+n;
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(s);
    third[i] = new JButton(img);
    keys3.add(third[i]);
    third[i].addActionListener(new TextAreaHandler());
    }

    main.add(keys3);
    int j=12;

    for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
    {
    String t=j+"";
    String m="icon";
    String n=".gif";
    String s=m+t+n;
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(s);
    fourth[i] = new JButton(img);
    keys4.add(fourth[i]);
    j++;
    fourth[i].addActionListener(new TextAreaHandler());
    }

    public class hindilang
    {
       public static void hindi()
          {
             lang lang = new lang()
               {
                 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
                   {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
                   }
                 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
                   {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
                   }
                 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
                   {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
                   }
               };
           }
    } 
            lang.setSize(800, 500); // set dimensions of window
            lang.setVisible(true);
    }
    }
```

The File is saved as hindilang.java and being compiled as `javac hindilang.java`, What am i doing wrong?? Please guide me

Tried the suggestions below but , still getting the same errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `public lang()` constructor method is missing a `'}'` at the end of its method definition just before the problematic line

Comment: After implementing your suggestion, i get errors at `lang.setsize(800,500);` and `lang.setVisible(true);` `class, interface, or enum expected`

Comment: The problem is that you named your instance as your class. Rename your class to Lang (via refactoring) and than it should work. It is common to capital the first letter of any word in a class name (e.g MyClass and not myclass)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `}` here is the corrected code

```
 abstract class lang extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{
boolean flag=false;
String firstRow[] = {">","=","*","_","<","{","(","'","?","-","!","[",")"};
String secondRow[] = {"|","#",".",":","&","@","]","/","}",",","$","^","~"};
String thirdRow[] = {"d","v","m","y","e","k","a","j","z","3","0","9"};
String fourthRow[] = {"r","b","p","o","h","w","g","x","1","7","5","4"};
String fifthRow[] = {"f","c","n","s","l","t","q","u","i","6","2","8"};
String sixthRow[] = {"Space","Back","Capslock","Clear","Show me mappings"};
JButton first[] = new JButton[13];
JButton second[] = new JButton[13];
JButton third[] = new JButton[12];
JButton fourth[] = new JButton[12];
JButton fifth[]=new JButton[12];
JButton sixth[]=new JButton[5];
int count=0;
Panel main = new Panel();
Panel keys1 = new Panel();
Panel keys2 = new Panel();
Panel keys3 = new Panel();
Panel keys4 = new Panel();
Panel keys5 = new Panel();
Panel keys6 = new Panel();
Panel text = new Panel();
TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
String strText = "";
private JLabel label1;
private JLabel label2;
private JTextField textField;

public lang()
{
super("Typing Application");
label1 = new JLabel("Type some text using your keyboard. The keys you press will be
"+ "highlighed and the text will be displayed");
add(label1);
label2 = new JLabel("Note: clicking the buttons with your mouse will not perform
any action");
add(label2);
textField = new JTextField(30);
textField.setEditable(false);
TextFieldHandler handler = new TextFieldHandler();
this.setLayout(new BorderLayout(6,6));
main.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));
keys1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,13));
keys2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,13));
keys3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,14));
keys4.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,12));
keys5.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,11));
keys6.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
text.setLayout(new BorderLayout(1,1));
text.add(textArea);

for(int i=0; i<13; i++)
{
first[i] = new JButton(firstRow[i]);
first[i].setSize(100,100);
keys1.add(first[i]);
first[i].addActionListener(new TextAreaHandler());
}



main.add(keys1);
for(int i=0; i<13; i++)
{
second[i] = new JButton(secondRow[i]);
second[i].setBackground(Color.white);
keys2.add(second[i]);
second[i].addActionListener(new TextAreaHandler());
}

main.add(keys2);

for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
{
String t=i+"";
String m="icon";
String n=".gif";
String s=m+t+n;
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(s);
third[i] = new JButton(img);
keys3.add(third[i]);
third[i].addActionListener(new TextAreaHandler());
}

main.add(keys3);
int j=12;

for(int i=0; i<12; i++)
{
String t=j+"";
String m="icon";
String n=".gif";
String s=m+t+n;
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(s);
fourth[i] = new JButton(img);
keys4.add(fourth[i]);
j++;
fourth[i].addActionListener(new TextAreaHandler());
}
}
}
public class hindilang
{
   public static void hindi()
      {
         lang lang = new lang()
           {
             public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
               {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
               }
             public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
               {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
               }
             public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
               {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
               }
           };
       }
} 
        lang.setSize(800, 500); // set dimensions of window
        lang.setVisible(true);
}
}
```